# Powershell script to install all the updates from MS software center

Tags: windows, powershell, sccm

I have a machine (windows 2012 R2) with MECM/SCCM client (MS software center).

Is there any powershell script which I could run on my machine to install all the avaiable software patches/updates ?

Comment: You have to write the script.  An Admin can remotely execute any command on the machine.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly do you need? Do you want to update / patch all of the software on your machine, or are you referring to updating Windows? If it's just about updating Windows, cursory Google search for `powershell check for updates and install` returns multiple promising results.